# How can I show labels for all x-axis values on a chart

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have a VB.Net project for web that includes a chart from the Visual Studio tool box. It's connected with SQL Server and everything works okay except that the labels of some of the x-axis values are missing.

This is my project at the moment. - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOf1r.jpg)   https://ibb.co/6vLWHq8

As you can see it jumps one value and shows next.

I want my chart to look like this. - [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsfmf.png) 
https://ibb.co/mtTwsZz

Comment: Your links to preview of how it looks now and how you want it to look are broke.

Comment: This is my project at the moment. - https://imgur.com/q1Lp0d3                                   
 .                               .         I want my chart to look like this.    - https://imgur.com/em1fiDS